# Consulta SQLLite

Tags: ionic, sqlite

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta en `sqlLite`, para una aplicación de `android` que estoy haciendo pero necesito hacer un `like` que busque independientemente donde esté el fragmento que estoy buscando.

```
select * from productos where  ( Prodescripcion like  

'%'+replace('Banda Ax ah',' ','%')+'%')
```

Este es el nombre del artículo completo:

> **BANDA AX100 DOBLE AH CARBON RACING T.W**

Answer (score 0):

**EDITO**

Replanteo el problema. Puede que tu sentencia sea correcta, pero que no reconozca el espacio como tal, una posible estrategia es sustituir los espacios también por su código `UNICODE` 160

```
select * from productos where ( Prodescripcion like replace(replace('Banda Ax ah',' ','%'),char(160),'%'))
```

Tu sentencia está bien construida, así que no quedan muchas opciones.

Comment: No me funciono con el ejemplo que me suministraste,
que otra cosa pudiese intentar

Answer (score 0):

con el siguiente codigo resolvi el problema

```
SELECT columnas
  from Productos
  where Prodescripcion like 'banda ax%ah%';
```